# E2597 ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib for architecture armv7 XE6 Delphi

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, delphi

I'm trying to compile an application in delphi XE6 for my Ipad Air with the latest version of ios, the yosemite version of mac and last xcode before had the version mountain lion and xcode 5 I compiled perfectly IOS version 7 but changing this version, when I try to compile I jump the following error:

```
[DCC Error] E2597 ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib for ARMv7 architecture 

[DCC Fatal Error] F2588 Linker error code: 1 ($00000001)
```

I loaded the libraries again and again, but always the same error, I searched the internet and no one has solution,

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Embarcadero has the following hot fix for the IOS Simulator that has a file called iPhoneOS8.0.defaultsdkpaths.  Deploy that file as documented.  Delete the SDK and then re-add the SDK.

http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30013